# Can I plug a 12v DC in to a 9v Pedal?

Tags: power-supply, current, 12v, guitar-pedal

pretty much as the title goes..
is it okay to plug an 12v DC power supply to 9v pedal?

*Power Supply* >> [Voodoo Lab ISO-5's Manual for reference](http://www.voodoolab.com/manuals/pedal_power_iso-5_manual.pdf)
*Pedal* >> [ADA GCS-5's Manual for reference](http://www.adaamps.com/Media/GCS-5%20USER%20MANUAL%2070141x%20v.0.1%20a.pdf)

p.s deeply sorry for this stupid question.

---

**EDIT: 4 April 2018 - 11:54 PM (GMT+7)** 
this question needs no further answer. It was my mistake for the lacking the experience which led to this nonsense-question. Thanks for the time and response, deeply appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but without a schematic for the "ADA 
GCS-5 GUITAR CABINET SIMULATOR" it's just a opinion.

Comment: Yeah,  you can,  but it will probably break the pedal, so i wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Can you use the High current 9V supply from the ISO-5?

Comment: @SteveG sadly I used the High Current 9v for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no certainty in an answer. It might be ok or not. It's your choice.

**9Vdc would be a safer bet**.  12Vdc could overheat the regulator parts inside depending on how it was designed for voltage and heat margin and limits to voltage differnce between input rectifed DC and output times load current.